# What word indicates that someone has spoken well?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's the phrase — and missing word — that can be used to indicate that someone has spoken well?

> She _____ herself quite nicely.

It's a bit of an odd word — something like efface or escape. It seems to be on the tip of my tongue but I can't remember it now...

The idea is that she defended herself well and did a good job saying what she had to say.

Comment: By "spoken well," do you mean "chose words well" or "enunciated clearly"?

Comment: Defended herself well. More in terms of they did a good job saying what they had to say.

Comment: _To express oneself_ is a phrase often used, especially with complementary words. The etymology is interesting, especially in phrases like _expressed milk_.

Comment: Rephrasing the sentence, you may simply say that **she was eloquent** or if you want to emphasize the job done  :  **she demonstrated such eloquence**.

Comment: Other posibility : **she argued quite nicely**

Comment: _Expressed_ herself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not really used for speaking [enunciating] well, **acquit** does fit your sentence.

> **acquit,** *v.*
>
> **5.d.** *reflexive.* To discharge oneself of a duty, responsibility, or office; to perform a task, accomplish a commission, etc.
>
> — [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1751) (probably paywalled)

One can certainly *acquit oneself well* in giving a speech or some other task. The verb seems only to be used positively; people do not generally acquit themselves badly.

Comment: My dictionary tags that definition with "archaic", so it's probably not the right one to refer to. The more modern definition is "conduct oneself or perform in a specied way".

Comment: But I suspect John Lawler's comment is what the OP is really looking for.

Comment: Hmm. OED didn't mark it as archaic in 2011. But you're probably right. It could be 6a. (This answer was really to give an answer. If you have a better answer, feel free!)

Comment: I was using my Mac's dictionary, which only has 2 senses, and this is 2a.

Comment: @AndrewLeach plus the phrase "acquit oneself": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquit%20oneself